# Name field convention for id field in Android Room Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dao

I have a problem with field naming convention in ROOM, especially in "id" field.

Every @Entity I created, my primary key I always called "id", just "id".

now I have to query database, with a POJO with @embedded @entities.

to avoid conflicts, I prefixed the tables...

```
public class FilialCruzaDto {

    @Embedded
    public FilialCruza filialCruza;

    @Embedded(prefix = "_filial_")     //_filial_
    public Filial filial;

    @Embedded (prefix = "_anio_")     //Para Evitar Conflictos de id
    public Anio anio;
}
```

The Entity "FilialCruza" ...

```
@Entity(tableName = "filialcruza",
        indices = {@Index(value = {"at_id"}, unique = true),
                @Index(value = {"filial_id"})}
)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public class FilialCruza implements Serializable {
...

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

...
```

another entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "filial",
        foreignKeys =
                {@ForeignKey(entity = TipoCosecha.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "tipo_cosecha_id"),
                 @ForeignKey(entity = TipoFilial.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "tipo_filial_id"),
                 @ForeignKey(entity = Anio.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "anio_id")
                },
        indices = {@Index(value="anio_id"), @Index(value="tipo_filial_id"), @Index(value="tipo_cosecha_id")}
        )
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public class Filial implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

 ... more fields ...
```

now the DAO.

```
// DTOs
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT filialcruza.*, " +
            "_filial_.*, " +
            "_anio_.* " +
            " FROM filialcruza" +
            " LEFT JOIN filial as _filial_ on filialcruza.filial_id = _filial_.id " +
            " LEFT JOIN anio   as _anio_ on _filial_.anio_id = _anio_.id " +
            " WHERE filialcruza.id = :id" +
            " ORDER BY filialcruza.nroParcela"
    )
    FilialCruzaDto getFilialCruzaDto(int id);
```

now the problem i got...
when I check FilialCruzaDao_Impl.java

I found this lines:

```
    final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "id");
    ...

    final int _cursorIndexOfId_1 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "id");
    ... 

    final int _cursorIndexOfId_2 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "id");
```

And that makes that each _cursorIndexOfId , _cursorIndexOfId_1 ,_cursorIndexOfId_2  takes the same field position in the _cursor.
But I prefixed the entities...

Should I change all my "id" on the entities ?
Any other solution?
Maybe select field by filed, and exclude "id" on joined tables ?

I hope i been clear.
Best Regards.
#StayAtHomeAndMakeGreatSoftware

Comment: I dont work on it before but I think you should to modify your query like `"SELECT filialcruza.*, _filial_.id as _filial_id, _anio_.id as _anio_id FROM ..."`

Comment: Yes! it looks like it work.   final int _cursorIndexOfId_1 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "_filial_id");  using wildcards like _filial_.* in the select don't work